# Gaussian process smoothing with eigen-decomposition

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, gaussian

From the book 'Gaussian Process for Machine learning', the author talked about the smoothing w.r.t eigen-decomposition. The prediction $f$ at training points can be written as
$$f=K(K+\sigma_n^2I)^{-1}y$$
where $K$ is the covariance matrix and $\sigma_n$ is the noise variance. Note that this is the predictions for training points.

Then the author use eigen-decomposition on $K$ such that $K=\sum^n_{i=1}\lambda_iu_iu_i^T$ where $n$ is the number of training points. Then, let the responses linear combined by $u_i$ such that $y=\sum^n_{i=1}\gamma_iu_i$. Next, the author gives the formula
$$f=\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{\gamma_i\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\sigma_n^2}$$

I don't get how can the outer product $u_iu_i^T$ cancel out. I tested the result and it is indeed correct. Any one knows the detail?

Comment: $u_i$ is orthonormal because $K$ is positive definite

Comment: I missed $u_i$ at the right-hand side of the second equation. It should be $f=\sum\frac{\gamma_i\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\sigma_n^2}u_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [version that I found](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf) has a different formula for $f$. Equation (2.36) in Section 2.6 (*Smoothing, Weight Functions and Equivalent Kernels*) states the following:

\begin{equation}
f = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\gamma_i\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \sigma_n^2}u_i.
\end{equation}
This makes sense, as $K(K + \sigma_n^2I)^{-1}$ is a matrix and $y$ is a vector, so $f$ should be a vector. I will show how to get this formula.

---

Since $K$ is a real covariance matrix, it is a positive-definite real matrix, which guarantees that it is orthogonally [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix). This means that the $u_i$ in the expression
\begin{equation}
K = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i u_i u_i^{\mathsf{T}}
\end{equation}
form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

\begin{eqnarray}
f &=& K(K + \sigma_n^2I)^{-1}y\\
&=& \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i u_i u_i^{\mathsf{T}}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_j u_j u_j^{\mathsf{T}} + \sigma_n^2 I\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}\gamma_{\ell} u_{\ell}\right)\\
&=& \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i u_i u_i^{\mathsf{T}}\right)\sigma_n^{-2}\left( \sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_j u_j u_j^{\mathsf{T}} +I\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}\gamma_{\ell} u_{\ell}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Recall the Taylor-MacLaurin series for $1 - x$:
\begin{equation}
1 - x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n~~\textrm{for}~~|x| < 1.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
1+ x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x)^n~~\textrm{for}~~|x| < 1.
\end{equation}
An analogous formula can be used for the square-matrix analogue:
\begin{equation}
I + A = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-A)^m~~\textrm{for}~~\left\Arrowvert A\right\Arrowvert < 1
\end{equation}
or if $A^N = O$, the zero matrix, for some $N$. This latter condition cannot hold for a positive-definite matrix.

Let's assume that this will work for $(\sigma_n^{-2}K + I)^{-1}$:
\begin{equation}
\left(I + \sigma_n^{-2}K\right)^{-1} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2})^mK^m.
\end{equation}

A valuable thing to notice about orthogonally diagonalizable matrices such as $K$ is that
\begin{equation}
K^m = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}\right)^m = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^m u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}.
\end{equation}
I'll let you verify that. Use the fact that the $u_i$ form an orthonormal basis.

Now we can write $f$ as
\begin{eqnarray}
f &=& \sigma_n^{-2} \color{red}{K}\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2})^m\color{red}{K^m}\right]y\\
&=& \sigma_n^{-2}\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2})^m\color{red}{K^{m+1}}\right]y\\
&=& \sigma_n^{-2}\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2})^m\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^{m+1}u_i u_i^{\mathsf{T}}}\right]\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}\gamma_{\ell} u_{\ell}\\
&=& \sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2})^m\left[\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^{m+1}u_i}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}\gamma_{\ell}\color{red}{u_i^{\mathsf{T}}}u_{\ell}\right]
\end{eqnarray}

Since the $u_i$ are orthonormal,
\begin{equation}
u_i^{\mathsf{T}}u_{\ell} = \delta_{i,\ell},
\end{equation}
the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). When we sum over $\ell$, the only term that "survives" will be the term for which $\ell = i$.

\begin{eqnarray}
f &=& \sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2})^m\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^{m+1}u_i\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}\gamma_{\ell}\delta_{i,\ell}\right]\\
&=& \sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2})^m\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\gamma_i\lambda_i^{m+1}u_i\right]\\
&=& \sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2})^m\lambda_i^{m}\right]\lambda_i\gamma_i u_i\\
&=& \sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-\sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i)^m\right]\lambda_i\gamma_i u_i\\
&=& \sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i)^{-1}\right]\lambda_i\gamma_i u_i\\
&=& \sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\gamma_i\lambda_i}{1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i}u_i\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\gamma_i\lambda_i}{\sigma_n^{2} + \lambda_i}u_i
\end{eqnarray}

---

Upon questioning from @yiming-che, I realized an easier approach. This approach is easy to see because $K$ is orthogonally diagonalizable. First, note that since the $u_i$ form an orthogonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, $I = \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}$. This gives us a simpler expression for $I + \sigma_n^{-2}K$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(I + \sigma_n^{-2}K\right)^{-1} &=& \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}\right)^{-1}\\
&=& \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i)u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}\right)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}

I claim that the last line can be re-written as
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i\right)u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}\right)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i\right)^{-1}u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}.
\end{equation}
Let's prove it by multiplying the original matrix and the suspected inverse.

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_j\right)u_ju_j^{\mathsf{T}}\right]\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i\right)^{-1}u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}\right]\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_j\right)\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i\right)^{-1}u_j~\underbrace{u_j^{\mathsf{T}}u_i}_{\delta_{i,j}}~u_i^{\mathsf{T}}\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_j\right)\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i\right)^{-1}u_j\delta_{i,j}u_i^{\mathsf{T}}\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i\right)\left(1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i\right)^{-1}u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_iu_i^{\mathsf{T}}\\
&=& 
\end{eqnarray}
This works as long as $1 + \sigma_n^{-2}\lambda_i \neq 0$ for each $i$.

Comment: yes, I missed the $u_i$. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Do you have an extra $-\sigma_n^2$ on the first term in Eq. 3?

Comment: @yiming-che: I have made some edits. Note that $(K + \sigma_n^2 I)^{-1} = \left[\sigma_n^2\left(\sigma_n^{-2} K + I\right)\right]^{-1} = \sigma_n^{-2}\left[\sigma_n^{-2} K + I\right]^{-1}$. We need to have $(\textrm{something} + I)^{-1}$, with "bare" I, to use the Taylor-MacLaurin series.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't explain my question clearly. I mean the first term $\sigma_n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iu_iu_i^T$ in Eq. 3. I don't know where this $\sigma_n^{-2}$ come from

Comment: @yiming-che: You found an error that I made. I have corrected it.

Comment: In Eq. 6, what norm is it for matrix $A$? Does that mean the generalization of Taylor  series cannot be applied to any positive definite matrix $\sigma_n^{-2} K$? the norm of $\sigma_n^{-2} K$ has to be less than 1?

Comment: @yiming-che: See my new addition to the answer.

Comment: Looks good to me. I accepted your answer.